# Passing javascript object reference to java function

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, vaadin

I have an application written in Java (Vaadin framework) which is working on server side. I also have some Javascript scripts that need to be executed in browser. Serwer should call certain js functions. To do that I want to pass reference to instance of javascript object to server. I'm testing my application in Firefox.

On server side I've exported function that Javascript should call.

```
JavaScript.getCurrent().addFunction("testfun", new JavaScriptFunction() {
        public void call(JSONArray arguments) throws JSONException {
            /* ... */
        }
    });
}
```

I call it on client side when button is clicked.

```
var that;
function EventsTest() {
    that = this;
}

EventsTest.prototype.init = function() {
    /* creating JQuery Button ...*/

    btnClick.onclick = function(){
        testfun(that);
    };

}
```

Note, that I can't call testfun in EventsTest function, because I need to wait for Vaadin app to be loaded.

When I load application and push the button firebug returns an error:

```
com.vaadin.client.ApplicationConfiguration SEVERE: (InternalError) : too much recursioncom.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (InternalError) : too much recursion
```

What do I do wrong? Is there any other way to do that, my script would be run in browser and called by server?

Comment: It seems that the message is clear. You have created a loop. When EventsTest is loaded, it calls `testfun(that)`, where that is EventsTest. replace `testfun(that)` by `testfun(alert("foo"))`.

Comment: Why 'that' is called? How can I prevent this behaviour?

Comment: Looking at your java code, what does `testfun` is `call(arguments)`. Because `that` is the argument of `testfun`, it does execute `that`. That's my guess. You can try to replace `that = this;` by `that = function(){/*some stuff here*/};`

Comment: I tried that before. `testfun(function(){that});` seems to work since I don't get any error in firebug, but printing `arguments.toString()` shows only `{}`

Comment: What if you let `testfun(that)` but replace `that = this` by `that = function(){/*some stuff here*/};` in EventsTest function ?

Comment: Ehh... I did `that = function(){this};` and then `testfun(that)`, it printed `[{}]` :< Temporarly I created variable `var globalVar = {}` to which I assigned `globalVar = this` in constructor. I can use my object like `JavaScript.getCurrent().execute("globalVar.someMethod()")` in my server code. It's not very pretty but it works for now...